How old is too old for Narnia?
In Prince Caspian, Peter and Susan are told that they won't return to Narnia again because they're "getting too old", although Edmund and Lucy aren't. In The Voyage of the Dawn Treader, Edmund and Lucy are told the same thing. In The Last Battle, Eustace and Jill are evidently not yet considered "too old" for Narnia.
How much can be deduced from the text about the ages of the Friends of Narnia at these times, and is it then possible to deduce exactly "how old is too old" for Narnia?
A couple of pieces of information to start us off: in Prince Caspian, "Lucy was going to boarding school for the first time", and in The Voyage of the Dawn Treader, it's been "a year" (in Earth time) since the events of Prince Caspian.

Related question: Was Susan ever able to return to Narnia?.

When I first read the title of the question, I misunderstood it. You're never too old to read Narnia.

Are you just looking for deductions from the text, or is the Outline of Narnian history so far as it is is known permitted?

@ClaraDíazSanchez I'd upvote the latter but probably wouldn't accept it (by itself, without any indication of how much can be deduced from the text). I'm interested to know the info from any canonical source, but would be even more interested to know if it can be derived from the text.

The Last Battle is an exception. || Aslan is older than time :-)

I think Lewis felt that puberty disqualified from entry to Narnia. Notoriously, at the end of the Narnia stories, Susan appears to be punished for entering adolescence and developing an interest in lipstick by exclusion from what in the Narnia mythos passes for heaven.

I do not believe that it is possible to obtain the children’s ages solely from evidence provided within the books, so it is necessary to supplement what information is available from another source, namely The Outline of Narnian History so far as it is known1. This was a document prepared by Lewis after the publication of the books, rather than being a guide to keeping the chronology straight as he worked on them, which may explain a couple of minor inconsistencies between the timeline and the books. While the ages of the Pevensie children are not explicitly given in The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe (TLTWaTW), the intervals between each of the following books is (albeit sometimes in a rather vague way), so it is at least possible to track how much the children age throughout the Chronicles.
Beginning with TLTWaTW, se see that the four children fall into two groups: “the older ones” of Peter and Susan, and the younger ones of Edmund and Lucy. So it seems as though Peter and Susan are close in age, there is then a gap, and then Edmund and Lucy are similar in age to each other. This is verified in the text when Edmund teases Lucy:

And Edmund gave a very superior look as if he were far older than Lucy
(there was really only a year's difference)

The Outline gives the dates of birth of the children as Peter in 1927, Susan in 1928,  Edmund in 1930, and Lucy in 1932. This is broadly consistent with what we read, except that the gap between the two groups is only two years, perhaps not as large as expected, and the gap between Edmund and Lucy is also two years, instead of the “only a year’s difference” mentioned. Possibly Edmund was born in December and Lucy in January making the age gap barely bigger than a year, or perhaps we can assign this to some imprecision in the text’s comment.
The book is set during the Second World War when the children have been evacuated, which is consistent
with the Outline setting the book in 1940. Accordingly Peter would be 13, Susan 12, Edmund 10, and Lucy 8 (depending of course on which month their birthdays fall in).
Prince Caspian opens with the children waiting at a railway station for the trains to take them to their boarding schools. We are told that Lucy was going to boarding school for the first time, and the omniscient narrator tells us that the adventures of TLTWaTW “had all happened a year ago”. This would make Lucy nine, which seems young to be going to boarding school, but is not impossible. While they explore the ruins of Cair Paravel, they make use of Edmund’s birthday present, an electric torch, which he had received “less than a week ago”. If the children are returning to school in September (which I believe would be normal for English schools) this would put Edmund’s birthday in late August or early September.
The children concur with the narrator, when towards the end of the book they note “it's only a
year ago since we came back from Narnia”. This agrees with the Outline which places the book in 1941. The children would thus be 14, 13, 11, and 9, and Peter and Susan are told they are too old to return. This gives us the first estimate of the cut-off age: 13 years old.
In The Voyage of the Dawn Treader Edmund and Lucy tell Caspian “It's a year ago by our time since
we left you just before your coronation”, placing the book in 1942, in agreement with the Outline. Peter would now be 15 and is said to be “working very hard for an exam and he was to spend the
holidays being coached by old Professor Kirke “ - presumably a school-leaving exam. At the end of the book, Edmund and Lucy are told:

"Please, Aslan," said Lucy. "Before we go, will you tell us when we
can come back to Narnia again? Please. And oh, do, do, do make it
soon."
"Dearest," said Aslan very gently, "you and your brother will
never come back to Narnia."
"Oh, Aslan!!" said Edmund and Lucy both
together in despairing voices.
"You are too old, children," said
Aslan, "and you must begin to come close to your own world now."

They should now be 12 and 10 years old - a lower cut-off than the one we saw before. This could be an indication that the cut-off arises from spiritual maturity, rather than chronological age. Lucy was always the most spiritual of the four, having the strongest bond with Aslan, and so maybe she needed less time to grow.
In The Silver Chair, Eustace and Jill are pulled into Narnia. Eustace is clearly younger than Lucy, but we are not told by how much in the text.  He and Jill are in the same class at school, so they should  be of the same age. The Timeline puts Eustace’s year of birth as 1933 and that the adventure is set in 1942 (the same calendar year as The Dawn Treader), making them approximately 9 years old. In the text Eustace refers to his adventure as occurring “last term” (rather than “last year”), so the interval between these two books is indeed quite short, less than a year.
In The Last Battle, Eustace and Jill are again drawn into Narnia. When they meet King Tirian, Eustace explains:

And we were here once before, ages and ages ago, more than a year ago
by our time

The Outline puts TLB as happening in 1949. This would be seven years after The Silver Chair. This seems to be a disagreement between the sources - I don’t think someone would describe a seven year gap as “more than a year”, although it is technically true. Before Eustace and Jill arrived, Tirian visited the Friends of Narnia in a dream, and saw Peter as

hardly full grown, certainly younger than Tirian himself, but his face
had already the look of a king and a warrior. And you could almost say
the same of the other youth [Edmund]… across the table sat a
fair-haired girl younger than either of these [Lucy], and on either
side of her boy and girl [Eustace and Jill] who were younger still

In 1949 Peter would be 22, but if it were a year or so after the events of The Silver Chair he would be about 17. This sounds closer to the description of a youth “hardly full grown”, i.e. just approaching manhood. In that case Eustace and Jill would be about 11 years old, which again seems to match the book better than if they were 16. Admittedly this was a special case, as like the other Friends of Narnia, they had been killed in a railway accident in England. But unlike the other Friends it seems that they were called by Aslan to help Narnia, instead of dying and entering Aslan’s country, so I would say that the same rules apply.
So the cut-off appears to be somewhere between 10 (Lucy) and 13 (Peter and Susan). But as Lewis remarked in one of his letters2 from 1953:

I don’t think age matters so much as people think. Parts of me are
still 12 and I think other parts were already 50 when I was 12.



Past Watchful Dragons: The Narnian Chronicles of C. S. Lewis by Walter Hooper (1979), pp 41-44, available from the Internet Archive.

The Collected Letters of C.S. Lewis, Volume 3 (1950 - 1963) (2009).




It probably doesn't help that the kids already grew up once, at the end of their first trip to Narnia. Lucy had already been a young woman and queen, it makes sense that she'd mentally and emotionally matured at an earlier age than her older siblings.

I don't think there is anything definitive, so I'm going to give my opinion. Feel free to downvote if you don't like it.
My take is that there is no specific age at which someone becomes "too old" to travel to Narnia. It depends on the person and their attitude.
I'm going to specifically relate this to another statement by Lewis, from the dedication of The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe to his goddaughter Lucy:

I wrote this story for you, but when I began it I had not realized that girls grow quicker than books. As a result you are already too old for fairy tales, and by the time it is printed and bound you will be older still. But some day you will be old enough to start reading fairy tales again…

I suspect that the two senses of "too old for Narnia" are related - that being to old to visit Narnia is related to "being too old for fairy tales". That would mean there is definitely a flexibility in "how old is too old" - that you aren't prevented from visiting Narnia on your thirteenth birthday (to pick a random example) just like you are not forced to stop reading fairy tales on the day of your thirteenth birthday. It may depend on attitude as well as age.
This is born out in my life. I thoroughly enjoyed the Narnia stories as a kid, revelling in the heroic tales and understanding (somewhat) the spiritual themes. As a teenager and young adult I would never have dreamed of reading "kids stories"; but now I'm very happy to settle down with a Narnia book, and I enjoy them in a completely different way. It may be the same with the Pevensies.

This is a reasonable take - it's not exactly what I'm looking for (actual ages of characters based on evidence in the text) and I'm not going to accept this answer, but I won't downvote it and may well upvote it.

So, Lucy could well have been on her way to boarding school at age 8 or 9 - many schools in the UK used a 'middle' school system then, that would have been the age for starting, having finished (perhaps) the local junior school.
Quite possible that Jill and Eustace are in the same class but different ages - the nominal cut off date for starting school is September, so Jill could be up to a year older. That also doesn't allow for being held back a year. or pushed up a year, to either repeat one, or be 'stretched a bit'.
Personally, I still enjoy the whole Narnian world in my 60s, so I don't think there is any 'too old' for it!

Hi Steve, welcome to Literature.SE! Your post looks like a comment on the answer by Clara Díaz Sanchez, and a comment posted as an answer is normally recommended for deletion. However, we do encourage "partial" answers that provide clarification on – or additional context for – an existing post. As this is what you've provided, I think your post qualifies as an answer rather than a comment, so I'm happy to upvote it, and I look forward to your next contribution. PS – don't forget to earn yourself a badge by completing our [Tour]. :-)
